# Help with Spivak's formulation of $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions.

Tags: calculus, integration

Chapter 15 of Spivak's *Calculus* deals with the first formal treatment of trigonometric functions.

After some exposition about 'what we want' $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions to do for us, Spivak provides the **first definition** of the chapter:

> $\boldsymbol{\pi}=2\cdot \displaystyle\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}dx$

That is to say, Spivak defines the symbol $\pi$ as twice the area of the unit semicircle.

Spivak then makes the following comment:

> Suppose $x$ is the length of the arc of the unit circle from $(1,0)$ to $P$; this arc thus contains $\frac{x}{2\pi}$ of the total length $2\pi$ of the circumference of the unit circle. Let $S$ denote the sector the is bounded by the unit circle, the horizontal axis, and the half-line through $(0,0)$ and $P$. The area of $S$ should be $\frac{x}{2\pi}$ times the area inside the unit circle: thus $S$ should have area $\frac{x}{2\pi}\cdot \pi=\frac{x}{2}=S_{\text{area}}$

...and goes on to define $\cos$ and $\sin$ as, "*The coordinates of a point $P=(\cos(x),\sin(x))$ on the unit circle which determines a sector whose area is $\frac{x}{2}$*"

My issue with this set up is that it seems we have completely abandoned a true formal derivation by first asserting, **without supplying a non-geometric proof**, that the circumference of a unit circle is $2 \pi$. Spivak's definitions of $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions appear to be fundamentally dependent upon that claim. Because of this, I decided to look back through the book to see if any exercises could help out.

---

**In Chapter 13, Problem 25** introduces the notion of the *length of a polygonal curve* which is denoted as:

> $\ell(f,P)=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{(t_i-t_{i-1})^2+[f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})]^2}$, where $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and $P=\{a,t_1,\cdots,t_{n-1},b\}$ is a partition of $[a,b]$

The **length** of $f$ is defined as the supremum of the set of all such $\ell(f,P)$.

Later on in this problem, we showed that **if $f'$ is bounded on $[a,b]$**, then, assuming $\sqrt{1+(f')^2}$  is integrable on $[a,b]$, we have that *length-of-$f$* $= \displaystyle \int_a^b \sqrt{1+(f')^2}$.

Now, returning to the context of the circle, we can quickly show that $f'$ is **not** bounded on $[-1,1]$ because if $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, then $f'(x)=\frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. Clearly, as $x \to -1: f'(x) \to \infty$ and as $x \to 1: f'(x) \to -\infty$. Therefore, $f'$ is not bounded on $[-1,1]$.

So, at least according to the exercises the reader has been exposed to, we **cannot** find the circumference of the unit semicricle through the following equation: $C_{\text{semi}}=\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)^2}$

Therefore, our only recourse is to somehow show that:

Letting $T=\{\ell(f,P): P \text{ is a partition of [-1,1]}\}:$ prove that $ \sup(T)=2\cdot \displaystyle\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}$, which is just saying that the circumference of the unit semi circle is equal to $\pi$.

After some algebra, that simplifies to proving that: $$\forall \varepsilon \gt 0: \exists P \in \mathcal P_{[-1,1]}: 2\cdot \displaystyle \int_{-1}^1
\sqrt{1-x^2}dx -\varepsilon \leq \sum_{i=1}^n
\sqrt{2-2t_i t_{i-1}-2\sqrt{(1-t_i^2)(1-t_{i-1}^2)}}$$, where $\mathcal P_{[-1,1]}$ is the set of all partitions of $[-1,1]$ and $t_{i-1}$ and $t_i$ are elements of $P$. It is not clear to me how one should prove this without any reference to trig functions.

---

**Final Comments**

Because $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is an even function, it will probably be more useful to pose the final question as: *What is the arc length of a quarter unit circle* described on $[0,1]$. On this interval, $f$ is a strictly decreasing function, which may make the calculation easier.

From geometry, we know that the arc length of quarter unit circle is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Using our definition of $\pi$ and the even property of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$, we would have that $\frac{\pi}{2}=2\cdot \displaystyle \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}dx$. Further, because Spivak has not yet provided us with any means of computing  $\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}$, we revert back to the Darboux definition which would be $\displaystyle \sup_{P \in \mathcal P_{[0,1]}}L(f,P)=2\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}dx=\inf_{P \in \mathcal P_{[0,1]}}U(f,P)$ where $\mathcal P_{[0,1]}$ is the set of all partitions of $[0,1]$.

Therefore, another approach to proving this is to show that:

- for every $P \in \mathcal P_{[0,1]}$, there is a $Q\in \mathcal P_{[0,1]}$ such that: $\ell(\sqrt{1-x^2},Q) \geq L(2\cdot \sqrt{1-x^2},P)$
- for all $P,Q \in \mathcal P_{[0,1]}$: $\ell(\sqrt{1-x^2},Q) \leq U(2\cdot \sqrt{1-x^2},P)$

Because $f$ is strictly decreasing, we have that for any $P \in \mathcal P_{[0,1]}$:

- $U(f,P)=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \left(2\cdot \sqrt{1-t_{i-1}^2}\cdot(t_i-t_{i-1})\right)$
- $L(f,P)=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \left(2\cdot \sqrt{1-t_{i}^2}\cdot(t_i-t_{i-1})\right)$, which may be useful.

Once again, I am not sure I see a way of  proving these statements. If anyone could provide proof of these statements, that would be great.

Comment: The book assumes that you know what $\pi$ is already, but $\pi$ has to be defined somehow.

Comment: @Somos I would like for my argument to be compatible with the text. I think your suggestion goes against that.

Comment: It's difficult to see where you want to go with this. As noted above the text assumes that you already know what $\pi$ is, the definition is there because we need to have some kind of definition to work with. Yes there is a flaw in the logic of the book, in that it assumes we know what $\pi$ is, but the reader is assumed to have enough knowledge to fill in the gaps, rather than the text having to explicitly demonstrate that $\pi$ is the circumference from that definition using area.

Comment: @SuzuHirose "where I want to go" is a direct proof as outlined in my post. From your comments, it seems as this is a very non-standard approach, but I am just trying to salvage that logical lapse in Spivak's presentation without tinkering with anything else.

Comment: Like any other textbook in mathematics, this book does assume some background knowledge.

Comment: @SuzuHirose fair enough. I suppose there is nothing *circular*, per se, about using 'outside knowledge' to define functions so that they behave in a particular manner. It is just unsatisfying. I feel like the proof structure I have proposed is the correct one, though...so I am hoping that someone can think of an argument

Comment: I didn't finish reading your question but let me comment: $\pi$ is problematic, in the sense that you need to philosophy about 'real numbers'. Do you think that a perfect 'platonic' circle exists?

Comment: I don't own a copy of the book and haven't taught from it in A Long Time, but my recollection is the comments about geometry may be taken as motivation. More analytically, the function $A:(-1,1)\to(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ defined by$$A(x)=\int_0^x\sqrt{1-t^2}\,dt$$is checked to be differentiable with strictly positive derivative, and therefore to be invertible. The sine function on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ is the inverse; we can extend to $\pm\pi/2$ by continuity, and then by $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin x$ for $|x|\leq\pi/2$, and finally to all $x$ by periodicity. [...]

Comment: This leaves work to be done, e.g., defining $\cos x = \sin(x - \pi/2)$, and checking $\sin'=\cos$ and $\cos'=-\sin$, which shows both functions are infinitely differentiable.

Comment: @SuzuHirose The book does *not*  assume any previous knowledge about $\pi$. The Greeks more or less defined $\pi$ as the circumference of the unit circle, Spivak's definition is in the same spirit.

Comment: @Sam The book does assume previous knowledge about $\pi$ as you can very easily confirm if you read it. It also assumes previous knowledge of $\sin$ and $\cos$. Again this can easily be confirmed by simply looking at the book. I didn't have time until just now to respond to you by going and looking at a copy, but congratulations if you were trying to make a fool of me by making me confirm something which was fairly obvious in the first place. Otherwise, I'm honestly not sure what the point is of making such a comment, nor why one person agreed with you.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang thank you for the comments. Would  it be correct to say something like: We are importing knowledge revealed through geometry (non-analytical) arguments to design functions (objects in 'analytical space')  that produce results (through analytical arguments) that correspond to / are in agreement with the geometric findings.

Comment: So is your question how to compute the circumference of a unit circle via an integral?

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, but without resorting to trig functions. I've played around with it and have not had much success. The methods I have accumulated through previous exercises do not seem to work. The approach  that I have been using is the approach specified in the **Final  Comments** section of my post. The expressions that I produce are not very friendly. I've been comparing $m_i^f \cdot (t_i-t_{i-1})$ with $\left(\sqrt{\frac{[g(t_{i-1}))-g(t_i)]^2}{[t_i-t_{i-1}]^2}+1}\right)\cdot (t_i-t_{i-1})$ and seeing if I can come up with clever new partitions that accomplish what I want.

Comment: @SuzuHirose It's not possible to "know" $\pi$ without having a definition of it, and Spivak does not assume it.  Before the chapter on trigonometric functions there's not a single mention of $\pi$ in the book.

Comment: @Sam it very clearly and obviously and evidently assumes that you know what pi, sine, cosine, etc. are.

Comment: @S.C. In a word, "yes," with all the qualifications that come with trying to say "why" about a definition. Mathematical definitions do often frame some intuitive idea; good definitions clarify, confirm, and extend the intuition that motivated them.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang thank you thank you. I feel like you always hook me up with what I am after hah. Cheers~~

Comment: One can show that $\ell(f) < \infty$ for your $f$ and that $\ell(f) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{-1 + \epsilon}^{1-\epsilon} \sqrt{1+ (f')^2}$. But I think the evaluation of these integrals is impossible without using trigonometric functions ($\arcsin$ in the present case), thus you will not able to show that $\ell(f) = \pi$ in an elemntary way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have missed multiple warnings by Spivak that the material you quote is motivational, and not a definition at all. The very second sentence of the chapter reads, in part,

> ...this chapter begins with some informal and intuitive definitions, which should not be scrutinized too carefully...

The very next sentence after your quote reads

> With these remarks as *background* [emphasis mine], the rigorous definition of the functions sin and cos now begins.

There is absolutely not a reliance on the assertion, at any point leading up to the formal definition (which is in a box labelled **definition**!), that the circumference of the unit circle has any particular ratio to its area.

Comment: I guess your comments (and others) amount to something like: We are importing knowledge revealed through geometry (non-analytical) arguments to design functions that produce analytical results that correspond to / are in  agreement with the classical geometric findings.  Is that right?

Comment: @S.C. That sounds like the idea. In principle, one could start with the formal definitions, but it would be dishonest not to illustrate how these definitions connect to the geometric motivation. After all, we’d never pick these particular integrals to invert if we weren’t interested in circles.

Comment: This is beyond ludicrous. Spivak's book is intended for university undergraduates specialising in mathematics. I doubt whether one in a million of these undergraduates would have no idea of trigonometry and have never heard that $\pi$ is the circumference of a circle, something which is taught to people around the age of ten or twelve. It's very difficult to understand where this notion comes from that Spivak wrote a book for mathematics-major undergraduates who had never heard of $\pi$, something like a biology book for undergraduate biologists who didn't know what fish or insects were.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Writing as a random passerby, I'm not sure what your first _this_ refers to, but in this (+1) answer I don't see any assertion that Spivak assumes readers have never heard of $\pi$. Rather, Spivak has written an exposition that acknowledges the geometric familiarity of $\pi$ to readers, but defines $\pi$ analytically, resting on nothing but a set of axioms for the real numbers. Pedagogically, Spivak took care to separate the exposition into intuitive motivation and rigorous deduction, as Kevin's answer documents. <> Does that not seem correct?

Comment: @SuzuHirose Seconded: I have no idea what you’re talking about, and whatever it is, it’s not anything in my comment or the one above.